# Rendering Component link with Tridion2011 OData Linking.svc

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We are using custom-written proxy class for handling the Web Service communication provided by Mihai Cadariu (screenshot attached) for resolving dynamic linking.
For forming the LinkUrl parameters to resolve dynamiclink/component link we are following the below sample approach. But its throwing error (stacktrace,debug error)attached .Please validate and provide the inputs where we are going wrong. Please let us know the parameters we are passing are correct or not

**Approach we used:**

-->We have two components Comp1,Comp2 (can be created of same/different schema guess it not any issue)

-->Comp2 is being used as component link inside Comp1 (we have a component link field in comp1)

-->Created two dynamic CT’s DCT1, DCT2 for each comp (CT’s have simple DWT, Default finish actions)
Note: also tried keeping  DD4T TBBs in similar set of CT’s as other approach but final got same error result

-->DWT code has --> SomeLink (to render component link so that LinkResolver TBB will resolve the links)
Also kept OTHWayLink (for cross checking)

-->Created two Pages Page1 (has Comp1+DCT1), Page2 (has Comp2 +DCT2) and published both pages to broker DB

-->Our goal is to resolve component link (Comp2) which is present inside Comp1 content so,

-->For GetDynamicLink() we provided parameters as given below. Which throwed error :400 (bad request) and exception in log trace attached above.

```
   Param’s List --> string targetPageUri, string targetComponentUri, string targetTemplateUri, string linkText, bool showTextOnFail, string linkTagAttributes

   Param’s we passed--> Page2 tcmid, Comp2 tcmid, DCT2 tcmid ,”some link txt”,true,”some string”;
```

-->For GetComponentLink()we provided parameters as given below. In this case we tried keeping both dynamic and non dynamic CT’s combination inside pages, Which also throwed error :400 (bad request) and exception in log trace attached above.

```
   Param’s List --> string targetComponentUri, string sourcePageUri, string excludeTemplateUri, string linkText, bool showTextOnFail, bool showAnchor, string linkTagAttributes

   Param’s we passed --> Comp2 tcmid, Page1 tcmid, DCT1 tcmid, “some link txt”,true,true,”some string” ;
```

we are refering [Live documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=CDWSLinkingAPI.xml&docid=reference_277A2D7264B04A39870C3FE18EF245BB&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocreference_277A2D7264B04A39870C3FE18EF245BB) for Linking.

Mihai Proxy Code sample: [image: Proxy class code]
Error message: [image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your odata website is not set up correctly in d:/inetpub/wwwroot/odata/bin as the error message is that Classes are not found.

Can you confirm you've installed/placed the correct SDL Tridion dll/lib and configuration XML files into your website?

Here is a great post about how SDL Tridion loads these files: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/how-tridion-content-delivery-loads-configuration-files-in-dotnet I'm sure once you've got the Odata application/website up and running this will work correctly for you.

Comment: We checked the installation of our Odata webservice.Yeah all required jar,config files are placed correctly in website. we followed the steps provided in Live documentation.We are able to query DB for Pages and component presentations using ODATA service and getting the expected results.Only this Linking webservice is not giving the expected result.So want to confirm whether the approach we mentioned above to pass the parameters for the Linking url is correct or not.Please validate the parameters we are passing and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

The Content Delivery linking service's parameters are documented on [this page](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/reference_277A2D7264B04A39870C3FE18EF245BB) (log in required). I'll paste an excerpt below, but you really should simply compare your strings to the parameters mentioned on that page.

```
Component Links
Command:/linking/componentLink (Java) or /linking.svc/componentLink (.NET)

Input parameters:
Parameter name        Default value
sourcePageURI         (none)
targetComponentURI    (none)
excludeTemplateURI    (none)
linkTagAttributes     (empty)
linkText              (empty)
showTextOnFail        true
showAnchor            false
```

From cross-checking these with the code you pasted in the screenshot, everything seems to line up.

That answer your question. But I doubt it solves your problem, since that seems (as John Winter suggested) more infrastructural: you're missing cd_link.jar in the relevant directory.

If you find it difficult to diagnose this problem further, I suggest contacting the original author of this custom code (or SDL or one of its partners). This will ensure you get help from someone who is experienced in troubleshooting the loading of JARs, DLLs and configuration files.